# Why is `dataclasses.asdict(obj)` > 10x slower than `obj.__dict__()`

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am using Python 3.6 and the `dataclasses` backport package from [ericvsmith](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses).

It seems that calling `dataclasses.asdict(my_dataclass)` is ~10x slower than calling `my_dataclass.__dict__`:

```
In [172]: @dataclass
     ...: class MyDataClass:
     ...:     a: int
     ...:     b: int
     ...:     c: str
     ...: 

In [173]: %%time
     ...: _ = [MyDataClass(1, 2, "A" * 1000).__dict__ for _ in range(1_000_000)]
     ...: 
CPU times: user 631 ms, sys: 249 ms, total: 880 ms
Wall time: 880 ms

In [175]: %%time
     ...: _ = [dataclasses.asdict(MyDataClass(1, 2, "A" * 1000)) for _ in range(1_000_000)]
     ...: 
CPU times: user 11.3 s, sys: 328 ms, total: 11.6 s
Wall time: 11.7 s
```

Is this expected behavior? In what cases should I have to use `dataclasses.asdict(obj)` instead of `obj.__dict__`?

---

**Edit**: Using `__dict__.copy()` does not make a big difference:

```
In [176]: %%time
     ...: _ = [MyDataClass(1, 2, "A" * 1000).__dict__.copy() for _ in range(1_000_000)]
     ...: 
CPU times: user 922 ms, sys: 48 ms, total: 970 ms
Wall time: 970 ms
```

Comment: Well, for starters, `asdict` will create and return *new dict object*, and recursive and convert any other data-class instances into dicts, whereas `__dict__` simply returns a reference to the namespace of the object, something you probably don't want to mutate, for example...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In most cases where you would have used `__dict__` without `dataclasses`, you should probably keep using `__dict__`, maybe with a `copy` call. `asdict` does a *lot* of extra work that you may not actually want. Here's what it does.

---

First, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict):

> Each dataclass is converted to a dict of its fields, as name: value pairs. **dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into.** For example:
>
> ```
> @dataclass
> class Point:
>      x: int
>      y: int
>
> @dataclass
> class C:
>      mylist: List[Point]
>
> p = Point(10, 20)
> assert asdict(p) == {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
>
> c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
> assert asdict(c) == {'mylist': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}
> ```

So if you want recursive dataclass dictification, use `asdict`. If you don't want it, then all the overhead that goes into providing it is wasted. Particularly, if you use `asdict`, then changing the implementation of contained objects to use `dataclass` will change the result of `asdict` on outer objects.

The recursive logic also has no handling for circular references. If you're using dataclasses to represent, say, a graph, or any other data structure with circular references, `asdict` will crash:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class GraphNode:
    name: str
    neighbors: list['GraphNode']

x = GraphNode('x', [])
y = GraphNode('y', [])
x.neighbors.append(y)
y.neighbors.append(x)

dataclasses.asdict(x) # crash here!
```

The `asdict` call in this example hits a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

---

Aside from that, `asdict` builds a *new* dict, while `__dict__` simply accesses the object's attribute dict directly. The return value of `asdict` will not be affected by reassignment of the original object's fields. Also, `asdict` uses `fields`, so if you add attributes to a dataclass instance that don't correspond to declared fields, `asdict` won't include them.

Finally, the docs don't mention it at all, but `asdict` will [call `deepcopy`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1028) on everything that isn't a dataclass object, dict, list, or tuple:

```
else:
    return copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

(Dataclass objects, dicts, lists, and tuples go through the recursive logic, which also builds a copy, just with recursive dictification applied.)

`deepcopy` is really expensive on its own, and the lack of any `memo` handling means that `asdict` is likely to create multiple copies of shared objects in nontrivial object graphs. Watch out for that:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
>>> @dataclass
... class Foo:
...     x: object
...     y: object
... 
>>> a = object()
>>> b = Foo(a, a)
>>> c = asdict(b)
>>> b.x is b.y
True
>>> c['x'] is c['y']
False
>>> c['x'] is b.x
False
```

Comment: OK, this makes sense. I guess I just looking for a "pythonic" way to convert a dataclass into a dictionary, without relying on dunder attributes like `__dict__`. I guess `vars(my_data_class)` accomplishes that.

Comment: @ostrokach don't do that. It does't *convert to a dict* it *returns the objects' namespace dict*.

Comment: My use-case is `df = pd.DataFrame([vars(dc) for dc in dcs])`, so a copy is made eventually.

But in general, yes, you are right.

Comment: @RickyLevi: That doesn't make sense. It sounds like you screwed up something else somewhere.